# CardView is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, cardview

Below is my code I have multiple `cardview` inside `LinearLayout` but after build I'm unable to scroll it. Half of the card view is hiding.

There is a screen shot

[image]

I want to scroll all of my `cardview`. I tried to add `scrollview` but it is not working. After adding `scrollview` all `cardview` is not working

This is what happening after adding `scrollview`.

[image: IAMGE2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eras.ppt.ras.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ll">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transblue"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/physics"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                    android:src="@drawable/sigma"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Physics"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Main Content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Profile"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Access Profile"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/practice"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundyello"
                    android:src="@drawable/sigma"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Practice"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Examination"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/study_material"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpink"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Access Study related stuff"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                    android:src="@drawable/sigma"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Setting"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Setting of App"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/bout"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundtransblue"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="About Us"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="PPT"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/chat"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundtransblue"
                    android:src="@drawable/quote"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Q/A"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Discussion"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also show the code with your scrollview? Where did you put it? Did you try to enclose the linearlayout of cardview with scrollview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `NestedScrollView` like below code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eras.ppt.ras.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ll">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transblue"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/physics"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                    android:src="@drawable/sigma"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Physics"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Main Content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Profile"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Access Profile"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/practice"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundyello"
                    android:src="@drawable/sigma"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Practice"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Examination"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/study_material"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpink"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Study Material"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Access Study related stuff"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                    android:src="@drawable/sigma"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Setting"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Change Setting of App"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/bout"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundtransblue"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="About Us"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="PPT"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/chat"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundtransblue"
                    android:src="@drawable/quote"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Q/A"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgray"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Discussion"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to Make `ScrollView` as your parent layout to Scroll your Controls

```
 <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!--add here all your controll-->
     </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

**CODE**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:context="eras.ppt.ras.MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/transblue" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/physics"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sigma" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Physics"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Main Content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Profile"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Access Profile"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/practice"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundyello"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sigma" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Practice"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Examination"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/study_material"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpink"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Study Material"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Access Study related stuff"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/setting"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sigma" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Setting"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Change Setting of App"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/bout"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundtransblue"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="About Us"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="PPT"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/chat"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundtransblue"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/quote" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Q/A"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/lightgray" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Discussion"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put `ScrollView` after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

and close this at the end of the file. `</ScrollView>`

And remove this lines from first `LinearLayout`

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to your ViewPager as static and only below portion of CardView is Scroll then below is perfect way to solve it.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#252562"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ll">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#969696"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/physics"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="#ff0000"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_account"
                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Physics"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/primary"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Main Content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/profile"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="#00ff00"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Profile"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Access Profile"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/practice"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="#ff0000"
                            android:src="@drawable/quila"
                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Practice"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/primary"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Examination"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/study_material"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="#00ff00"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/quila2" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Study Material"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Access Study related stuff"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/setting"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="#ff0000"
                            android:src="@drawable/sea"

                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Setting"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Change Setting of App"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/bout"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="#265614"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="About Us"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:background="#546633" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="PPT"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/chat"
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="190dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:background="#969696"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            android:padding="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Q/A"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/primary"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Discussion"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and if you want to scroll both then put ScrollView as your main layout and remove inner scrollview.